# Regex error occurs when trying to run Workflow Template on my local machine for Google Cloud Platform

Tags: bash, workflow, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a workflow template that looks like this:

```
template_name='reddit_etl'
cluster_name='spark-job-reddit'
yesterday_date=$(date -d '-1 day' +'%Y-%m-%d')
bucket=gs://r-etl

gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates create $template_name --region "us-east1" &&

gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster $template_name --region "us-east1" \
--cluster-name=$cluster_name \
 --scopes=default \
 --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
 --master-boot-disk-size 20 \
  --num-workers 2 \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 20 \
--metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=pandas==1.0.4 praw==7.0.1' \
--initialization-actions \
--image-version 1.3 &&

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates \
 add-job pyspark $bucket/reddit-job/reddit_daily_load.py \
--step-id submissions_etl \
--workflow-template=$template_name \
--region "us-east1" &&

bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
 data_analysis.submissions \
 $bucket/submissions_store/${yesterday_date}".json" &&

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates \
 add-job pyspark $bucket/spark-job/reddit_spark.py \
--step-id submission_calc_etl \
--workflow-template=$template_name \
--region "us-east1" &&

gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates instantiate $template_name --region "us-east1" &&

 bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
 data_analysis.submission_analysis \
 $bucket/spark_results/${yesterday_date}"_calculations/*.json"
```

When I run this bash script:

```
bash reddit_workflow_template.sh
```

this gets returned:

```
reddit_workflow_template.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
' must be match of regex [a-zA-Z0-9][-_a-zA-Z0-9]{1,48}[a-zA-Z0-9]GUMENT: Template id 'reddit_etl
reddit_workflow_template.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
```

And everything fails from there.

I've run gcloud commands through bash before and I never got errors like this. And the name of my template should still match the regex pattern.

Comment: This might help: `dos2unix reddit_workflow_template.sh`

Comment: @Cyrus This fixed it for me. Thank you!